# Airflow wait dependency instead of skipping dependency

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

is there a way to create just wait dependency between tasks, because, I do have a task array for example:

`tasks_name = [task1, task2, task3]`

They are calling like that:

```py
    task1 >> task2
    task2 >> task3
    task2 >> task_4
    for task3 in tasks_name:
        [task3] >> task4
    task4 >> task5
    task5 >> task6
```

but if I remove dependency between task4 and task3, it is not running after all `tasks_name` finish:
[image]

and if I add this dependecy, it will skip, and I do not want to skip, if I run at least one task3
[image]

I am using BranchOperator to validate if it skips or not.

I need a help,

1- If I can run task 4 if I have at least one task3 running

2- If I can add dependecy between task 3 and task 4 to run just when all task 3 have finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution!!!

I am using the first option

`1- If I can run task 4 if I have at least one task3 running`

Using the param `trigger_rule="none_failed"` because the default is `trigger_rule="all_success"` so when it found a skip status, it skip the rest of the flow.

The code working as expected is like:

```py
conditional_validate = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='conditional_validate',
        python_callable=conditional_validate,
        provide_context=True,
        trigger_rule="none_failed",
        dag=dag)
```

[image]